# select string that doesn't contain a substring/field

Tags: oracle-12c, if-not-exists

`TableA.content` is `varchar2(4000)`, which was populated from a CLOB value that contains markup and text for a website, paragraphs actually.
`TableB.keyword` contains a string that I want to find in `TableA.content`.

I want to do something like this, but it is not quite right.  What am I missing?

```
select tableA.content from TableA
where (select distinct(TableB.keyword) from TableB) not in TableA.content;
```

So I want all the rows in `TableA` that don't have any of the values in `TableB.keyword`.

I was checking out `MATCH` or `CONTAINS` but I can't get it right using those.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem could be summarised like this:

> Select a row from `TableA` if no row exists in `TableB` such that `TableB.keyword` is a substring of `TableA.content`.

It would probably be fair to say that the previous answer implements roughly the same logic. At the same time, it does so in a less straightforward way, in my opinion. The query below matches the proposed logic more directly and is arguably easier to follow:

```
SELECT
  content
FROM
  TablA
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      TableB
    WHERE
      TableA.content LIKE '%' || TableB.keyword || '%'
  )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery will likely return several rows, but will be expected to return only one and will give an error. Also, the `in` sql operator is intended to work on sets rather than strings.

If your `tableA` has an ID, you can try the following query instead:

```
select tableA.content
from TableA
where ID not in (
  select distinct a.ID
  from TableA a
  join TableB b on (a.content like ('%'||b.keyword||'%'))
  -- for case insensitive matching use instead:
  -- join TableB b on (lower(a.content) like ('%'||lower(b.keyword)||'%')) 
  );
```